# ubuntu12.04 the system network service is not compatible with this version

Tags: wireless, internet, network-manager

After installing [libdirectfb-1.2-0_1.2.8-5ubuntu2_i386.deb] file for trying [Realsoft 3D]
on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, suddenly and without restarting the internet went off and the signal and the Network-Manager are off too, i tried to lunch the [Network-Manager] from terminal and it didn`t work

I found this solution [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001421) but i am not sure of how to use it, because i don't know what to download from those [Link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager-dbg), and i hope someone Professional could advise me because i am new on Ubuntu, this is my first month

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for no one I solved it.

As written above you have to Install only ([libnm-glib4_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libnm-glib4)) using terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/USERNAME/Desktop/libnm-glib4_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

In my case I put it on the desktop to make it easier
and if it didn`t work for any reason, install the other 2 Lib files and the 
;

[libnm-util2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libnm-util2)

[libnm-glib-vpn1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libnm-glib-vpn1)

Don’t forget to install the [network-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager)

and `sudo apt-get update`

Hope there is someone having the same problem and get this help.

The Original [Article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001421)